# service calls hang on the second page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, spring-mvc, h2

I've got a spring web application where I load the UI data using web services. The DB I use is H2 and I've posted a sample service where I use it fill a `select` element. Below is the spring service.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getAllOutlets", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody ModelMap loadOutlets(){
    List<Outlet> outlets = dataViewService.getAllOutlets();

    ModelMap model = new ModelMap();
    model.put("outlets", outlets);
    return model;
}
```

This service is consumed by the following get call.

```
function getOutlets(){
var element = $('#outlets select');
element.empty();

$.get('/getAllOutlets',function(response){
    for(var i = 0; i < response.outlets.length; i++ ){
        element.append("<option id="+ response.outlets[i].outletId + " >" + response.outlets[i].name + "</option>" );
    }
});
}
```

When I run the web application, the data is loaded to the UI with no hangs whatsoever. But When I refresh the page, the data doesn't get loaded to the UI. I checked with firebug and I could see that all the calls have loading icon infront of them. ( No break points have added ). Another thing I noticed is that, Only the services that require DB access is getting hanged in the second call. For example, I've got a service which read a system properties file and send the value. It doesn't get hanged while all the other DB required services get hanged. Below is a screen shot of the calls in firebug. ( Hope you understand )

[image]

Update :

```
function populateUIMajorGroups(){
var uiElement = $('.item-group-button').first();

$.get('/getAllMajorGroups', function(data){
    if(data.majorGroups.length != 0){
      $('.panel_list').empty();
      uiElement.empty();
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < data.majorGroups.length; i++){
      var clone = uiElement.clone();
      clone.append("<h3>" + data.majorGroups[i].description + "</h3>");
      clone.attr("id", data.majorGroups[i].majorGroupId);
      $('.panel_list').append(clone);
    }

},'json');
}
```

The above code runs perfectly without any hang! As you can see in the screenshot! Why is this happening to only GET methods?

Comment: As per your screenshot it seems that getItemByMajorGroup call has succeded, Isn't it a db interaction call? Set debug see if calls are blocking ?

Comment: Yes I noticed that! I've added that function to my question too! It's an ajax call not a get. So it runs fine! I guess the problem occurs only in get calls!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting `json` from your `server` but you didn't use it, add the `third parameter` `json` as `datatype` in your `get function` like:

```
$.ajax({url:'/getAllOutlets',dataType:'json',type:'GET',
    success:function(response){
      if(response.outlets && response.outlets.length)//check here that it is a json
      {
          for(var i = 0; i < response.outlets.length; i++ ){
              element.append("<option id="+ response.outlets[i].outletId + " >" + response.outlets[i].name + "</option>" );
          }
      }
    }//End success
});
```

Docs http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I added this to my code and the issue is still there! I've updated the question a little bit! one method with a .ajax call completes successfully without any hangs as you can see on the screen shot.

Comment: Try the above if it works here, I used `jQuery.ajax` function instead of `jQuery.get`. May be it solves your problem.

Comment: Above doesn't work and I changed the hanging methods to ajax calls! but it doesn't work! Now even ajax calls hangs!

Comment: Then I think you should not check all `ajax calls` at once. Try to call one by one then you can debug easily and find the problem from which `ajax call`.

Comment: I'm trying that now and now even that single one I'm checking hangs with no reason! Not even an error message!

Comment: Then add `static json` to your `server page` and then check.

Comment: I've found that the issue is not with the ajax call! I added a debug point in a service and it gets to the point where I access the DTO layer! so there is some issue with the DTO layer!